# How can I connect to the same github repository for heroku and Ditigitalocean?

Tags: heroku, digital-ocean

Is it possible to do that connection???
I have a project which I want to run on heroku at the same time on Digitalocean.
I tried it but heroku returns an error if I remove the Procfile, which Digitalocean does not require.
DO works if I remove the `Procfile` but heroku errors, and vieversa.

Comment: Your explanation is unclear.  Is there one "procfile" or two of them with different content for Heroku and DigitalOcean?  If there is one, does DigitalOcean require it or not?  If DigitalOcean doesn't require it, will it **ignore** it?

Comment: Just one Procfile which when I include in the project makes DO not to deploy, when I remove it it deploys on Do. The same Procfile is required by heroku so when I exclude it heroku errors.

Comment: So you are saying that DigitalOcean requires it to NOT be there?  (How lame!)

Comment: Anyhow, I think you should be able to solve this with git submodules; see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create different branches for your project and then serve to each server respectively with their needs.

Comment: Ironically this is in fact the solution I went with.